# what do the parameters of bbox mean in pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to take a screenshot of a delimited area of the screen using Pillow (python), but I'm having trouble figuring out what the four parameters mean. I searched the docs, but they only say it is a bbox, but not what they mean, someone know where is this specified?

This is the code I am trying to use, what do 'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd' represent?

```
ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(a,b,c,d))
```

Comment: coordinate of left,upper,right,lower I believe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to the [doc](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html)

Parameters: bbox – What region to copy. Default is the entire screen.

so as for the box the parameters are positions

Parameters: box – The crop rectangle, as a (left, upper, right, lower)-tuple.

As @Yury mention it below, a better explanation then the documentation can be found  on this blog [here](https://chayanvinayak.blogspot.com/2013/03/bounding-box-in-pilpython-image-library.html)

Comment: thanks, this link contains an image that explains a little more what those parameters are:

http://chayanvinayak.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/bounding-box-in-pilpython-image-library.html

Comment: Thanks Yuri for that image. All of this information should be in the API documentation where the argument states "bbox". Thanks again.